Tensor product of dg modules over dg categories
I am studying this survey by Keller and I am stuck on page 11 (chapter 3.8 about Morita equivalence) where he has the notation of the tensor product between two dg modules. Let $A$ and $B$ be small dg categories. Let $X$ be an $A$-$B$-bimodule, that is a dg functor as defined in chapter 3.1 of the survey, a functor
$$A^{op}\otimes B\to C_{dg}(k)$$
where $C_{dg}(k)$ is the dg category of complexes as defined in 2.2. Keller then defines a functor $G\colon C(B)\to C(A)$ ($C(A)$ and $C(B)$ are the categories of dg modules as defined in 3.1) by $GM=\mathcal{Hom}(X,M)$ where $M\in C(B)$. He then claims that this functor has a left adjoint $F$ which sends an $A$ dg module $L$ to $L\otimes_{A}X$. It is this tensor product that I cannot understand how it is defined. I know how I can define the tensor product of two dg categories but I cannot see what the definition is for the dg functors $L$ and $X$ ($X$ is also actually a bimodule which confuses me more).
